# How to configure Linux to run benchmarks as stable as possible?

Tags: linux, performance, gentoo, benchmark

I have several long running benchmarks (SPEC CPU 2006 benchmarks) to run on a Linux server.

The server is running Gentoo Linux with a Linux Kernel 3.6.11.

I saw some big differences between different runs and I'm thinking that it could be some problem with my configuration.

I'm the only user of the server.

I have already done several configuration changes:

- I have disabled the CPU frequency scaling feature of the kernel.
- I have removed all cron jobs
- I made sure that there were no frequency scaling in the BIOS

Is there some others things I should configure/disable/enable in the kernel or on the installation ?

I do not need to make the server faster, but I want to make sure that the benchmarks are not encountering pertubations

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Disconnect from network

   Do you have physical access to the server? Is it possible to disconnect the server from network while running the test? Serving network request (e.g. http/sql) during the test will very likely affect  theresult.
2. Disable cron job

   Running a cron job during the test will also affect the test result, especially a heavy one like indexing or backup routine.

Comment: I have physical access, but I would prefer no disconnecting the network so that I can run benchmarks from home too. There are no accesses to the server, expect broadcasting from the network. Do you think that is enough to cause variations ? 
I will disable cron jobs but I don't think there is any.

Comment: how much discrepancy you are seeing? Maybe posting the result will help pinpoint the reason.

Comment: @JohnSiu is right. _Some_ discrepancy is to be expected. If there is too much discrepancy, perhaps the benchmark itself is flawed (doing something that gets cached the first time around, and you see just lookup costs later, for example).

Comment: I'm seeing sometimes up to 30% differences in the scores of the benchmarks between two runs. Normally, this benchmark suite is known to be very stable and very well done.

Comment: The SPEC test suits are not free so I cannot test them. How long the benchmark takes per run? Is it practical to do 5 or more runs from a script and see if there is a trend?

Comment: Each benchmark takes about 30-60 minutes to complete and I'm running each of them with 4 different configurations. It means about 3hours.

Comment: May I suggest running 1 configuration 3 or 4 times in a role, with a script. Let it run over night so you can pickup result in the morning.